# NS_SWIFT_NAME not working with a "." (dot) in the base name

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

> Error: NS_SWIFT_NAME not working: imported declaration SandwichBreadType could not be mapped to SandwichPreferences.BreadType.

I've copied the same example as https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/renaming_objective-c_apis_for_swift and get the warning above. On the swift side of things that enum doesn't exist.

Works fine if I remove the dot.
I'm trying to fake some namespaces on the swift side even if objC doesn't have any.

What am I doing wrong?
Does that work only for some xCode version or swift version and above ?
I am at xCode 11.6 Swift 5.0

Comment: Are you sure you put the enum declaration into the same .h file where you put `@interface SandwichPreferences` and `@interface Sandwich`?

Comment: @OOPer : Wow I didn't even try reading the doc. I assumed I could just put anything there.

Please post as answer.

Comment: Please post an answer by yourself. Your assumption may be very common among starters of reading Apple's doc. Sharing your experience would help those people.

Comment: I wanted to give you credit but sure :)